# Install artifacts from artifactory to local repository

Tags: maven, installation, repository

I have an artifactory which stores artifacts, this is a given pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.test2.test3</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-gen</artifactId>
    <version>v2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test dynamic web layer</name>
</project>
```

How can I install the given artifact to my local repository?

mvn install, mvn install:file and others can't help. Pretty frustrated about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use it as a dependency which will automatically download the artifact and put it into your local repository.

Otherwise you can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) by using the `get` goal:

```
mvn dependency:get -DartifactId=WhatEver -DgroupId=XX -Dversion=xxx -Dclassfier=..
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, however the given command give me this:
"Required goal not found: dependency:get" so i think the given plugin is not in the repository

Comment: Ah you migh using an older version so should change that into `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get ...` which should work.

Comment: Oh, this is perfectly work and fine... One more question if you may allow me:
- Is there another solution for that? If i create a pom.xml from this information which i copied in my open post and run mvn install ??? 
(because if i do this, it will still download the given .jar but with almost no information on it, it will be a ghost jar...). So i think maybe i do something in a wrong way.

Comment: I really don't understand the supplemental question. What would you like to achieve ?

Comment: I got a hint from my leader, that this functionality (jar download) can be achived with a pom download (from artifactory) and "mvn install" (with the given pom)... I want to know what he was thinking/meaning but without the direct question, so i asked you... 
Thank you for your help so far...